# How can I build a circuit to convert sine waves to square waves at up to 1MHz?

Tags: sine

May I ask how do I convert sine waves to square waves at a frequency up to 1MHz? 
New to digital electronics. Have done some research but not sure which circuit to use/ which is suitable. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Components I have:

74LS14 Hex Schmitt trigger inverter

74HC132 Quad 2-input Schmitt trigger NAND gate

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: It is his own question actually..

Comment: suppose you provide 2MHz, at ONE millivolt. Will you accept a 0.1 volt output, with period of 500 nanoseconds +- 200 nanoseconds, with rise and fall times of 100 nanoseconds, sort of?

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question. If the existing answer was not satisfactory, you should not have accepted it.

Comment: It all depends on your input amplitude min~max and source impedance (ohms, max)),  DC biased or AC coupled.  The Schmitt input requirements may not solve this and it was  incorrect or premature to say this linked (dupe) answer will solve your question without more specs. That answer certainly wont work in every case. A far better solution is to avoid Schmitt triggers unless you can tolerate jitter and far better use a linear CMOS with input filter.

Comment: The 74HC132 needs DC bias and > 2/3Vdd input pk-pk and wont work with < 2/3 Vdd input swing

Comment: For a better answer see mine https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346423/which-cmos-logic-families-can-safely-be-used-to-construct-linear-circuits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say the voltage of the sinewave and you do not say the amount of output voltage and current you need.

The 74LS14 needs a supply voltage of 5V and produces an output of about 0.1V to +3.5V at a few mA.
The 74HC132 needs a supply voltage from 2V to 5.5V and produces an output almost the same as its supply voltage at a few mA.

The datasheets show the ranges of input signals needed.